# Json Format using jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, rest

I want to form json in the below format using jquery, But wasn't able to achieve the expected format. My actual result is printing only the last key value pairs.

Code Snippet from ejs file

```
    var count=0;
    var meta=[];
    $.each(this.metadata, function(key, value){
    <input type="text" id="keyfun" name='meta[count].key' value='<%=key%>' size="40"/>
    <input type="text" id="valfun" name='meta[count].value' value='<%=value%>' size="40"/>
    count++;
```

metadata object contains key and value pairs. Need to print key and value in json     format.Please advise on this..

```
Expected Result:
{"meta":
[
{"key":"user ","value":"test1"},
{"key":"test","value":"test2"},
]
}
```

Actual Result

```
{
 "meta": [
         {
          "key": "test1",
          "value": "test"
         }
         ]
}
```

---

I have added the metadata object values into array and then trying to iterate from array of objects.
1)Adding the metadata values into array
$.each(this.metadata, function(key, metaValue){arr.push({key1: key, value1:  metaValue});
});
2) iterating the array objects
$.each(arr, function (index, metaValue) {
'/>
' size="40"/>
});

Output:{"metaValue": {"key1": "mobile","value1": "wsmuser"}}

I got last key and value pairs, not getting the full key and value pairs...Please advise on this. 
Regards,Raj

Comment: Can you please post the full rendered javascript from the browser?  That bit of code which looks somewhat like javascript is clearly not complete.

Comment: I can't think of any reason at all why you would want to do something like this ... but I guess the jquery funktion .serializeArray(); does already do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Red about how [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) works. I'd do it somhow like this:

```
var meta=[];
$.each(this.metadata, function(index, metaValue){
  <input type="text" id="keyfun" name='metaValue.key' value='<%=metaValue.key%>' size="40"/>
  <input type="text" id="valfun" name='metaValue.value' value='<%=metaValue.value%>' size="40"/>
});
```

Of course if `this.metadata` is an array of objects, each with key and value. I didnt test it, but it would be something like this:)